# Optional property class in typescript

Tags: typescript, properties, option-type

I'm new to typescript. What is the utility of optional properties in typescript? And what is the difference between:

```
a?: number;

a: number | undefined;
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties gives examples of where you might want to use them

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Optional property:
In Typescript you can declare a property in your interface which will be optional. Suppose you have a interface for employee and middle name is optional then your code will look like this:

```
interface IEmployee {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  middleName?: string;
}
```

When someone will use your interface IEmployee then middleName will be optional but firstName and lastName is compulsory.

```
let emp: IEmployee = { firstName: "Hohn", lastName: "Doe" }
```

Pipe Operator:
Sometimes you want that a variable can hold multiple type. If you declared a property as number then it can hold only number. Pipe operator can tell typescript that it can hold multiple type. Other case where pipe operator is very useful when you return something from function and can return multiple type depend on condition.

Hope it will help

Comment: So it is important in the compatibility of the types. The same example works for class, right?

Comment: Pipe operator will work in class too but optional property is only for interface. There is no meaning of optional property in class.

Comment: I want to do the same stuff, but make some optional properties compulsory based on the value of other property in the same interface.

Example: I wanna make middleName compulsory if firstName is "foo1"

Comment: is it safe to refer to `emp.middleName` ?    For example, `hasMiddle = !!emp.middleName`.   Or can this cause "emp doesn't have property middleName" kind of issues?

Answer (score 72):

## Parameters

The difference between an optional parameter, and a parameter type `number | undefined` is that you don't have to supply an argument...

```
function a(a?: number) {
    return a;
}

function b(a: number | undefined) {
    return a;
}

// Okay
a();
b(1);

// Not okay: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
b();
```

This applies to functions, methods, and constructors.

## Strict Null Checks

If you switch on strict null checks, you'll find that any optional parameter, or property, will get a union type automatically. That means `id` in the below example has the type `number | undefined`, even though you only specified `number`:

```
// With strict null checks, this:
class Example {
    id?: number;
}

// ... is the same as this:
class Example {
    id?: number | undefined;
}

// ... and this:
class Example {
    id: number | undefined;
}
```

I would recommend using the first example as it keeps your syntax consistent between properties and parameters.