# How can i create type with just part of predefined available keys?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

How can i create type with **just part** of predefined available keys?

i do something like:

```
export type MyKeys = 'aa' | 'bb' | 'cc';

export type MyType = {
    [k in MyKeys]: any;
};
```

and use it:

```
let mySpecialObj: MyType = {
    aa: 'key',
    // bb: 'key', <-- without this for example
    cc: 'key'
}
```

*( Other question:
As i see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942141/optional-property-class-in-typescript), this question are not the same because i meant for a type with iterator key declaration: [k in MyKeys]: any; )*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optional property class in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942141/optional-property-class-in-typescript)

Comment: it's not exactly the same as the link you post, because it's hidden in iteration key "[k in MyKeys]: any;"

Comment: i don't think "embedding" a solution in a loop would make it a totally different solution. Anyway, it's just a duplicate proposal, not mine to judge now :) this is not to express a judgement on the question, it's more for search engines and stuff like that

Comment: see my previous comment edit, you don't need to justify yourself in an edit, your question won't be deleted, it has an upvoted answer, don't take these flags as personal ;)

Comment: i know the possibility of adding question mark for specific field, and even though it's not help me understand that. so this question asked for people like me that still have issue with this, when it not for specific field

Comment: should i remove the duplication explanation from the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found the solution,

just to add question mark '?' in the end of the declaration of the key part
like:

```
export type MyType = {
    [k in MyKeys]?: any;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just mark all fields as optional:

```
export type MyKeys = 'aa' | 'bb' | 'cc';

export type MyType = {
    [k in MyKeys]?: any;
};

let mySpecialObj: MyType = {
    aa: 'key',
    cc: 'key'
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your fastest help. just found also.