# How to create a TypeScript object with only selected properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-dynamodb

I have a TypeScript object that looks like this:

```
class User {
  id: string = "";
  location: string = "";
  displayName: string = "";
  otherAttribute: string = "";
}
```

How can I create an object of type User, with only the fields I want it to have?

For example, I want to be able to create a User object that only contains **id** and **displayName**, but without the **location** and **otherAttribute** properties. I need to create a new object without unwanted properties to use DynamoDB DataMapper, which is an ORM library that interfaces with DynamoDB and uses the class properties to map to the DynamoDB table attributes dynamically. This was working fine before using plain JavaScript because I didn't declare any property in my JavaScript User class but now need to for TypeScript. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Where is your interface ?

Comment: Why don't you create an object with null values in location and otherAttribute fields and then remove them using **delete**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optional property class in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942141/optional-property-class-in-typescript)

Comment: @RandyCasburn not quite because optional or not, when the object is created, the property is still there for the object.

Comment: @RandyCasburn it's not so much "swimming against the tide" but rather trying to find a solution to a practical problem. I'm using a library (AWS DynamoDB DataMapper) that was designed for JavaScript rather than TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding all you need is to create an instance of type `User`, with only certain properties.

You can do it in several ways. The most straightforward way is to make use of either the `Pick` or `Omit` utilities from TypeScript, like so:

```
const cherryPickedInstance: Pick<User, "id" | "displayName"> = {
  "id": "123",
  "displayName": "Oliver" 
};

// or make use of Omit
const omittedInstance: Omit<User, "otherAttribute" | "location"> = {
  "id": "1234",
  "displayName": "Sam" 
};
```

[EDIT]
I didn't fully grasp your requirement. But if you want to just make some of the properties partial and keep the rest of properties from `User` intact, then make use of the `Optional` utility, like so:

```
type Optional<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<Partial<T>, K> & Omit<T, K>;
```

Then you can setup your class like this, with all properties `Partial` by default:

```
class User {
  id: string = "";
  location: string = "";
  displayName: string = "";
  otherAttribute: string = "";

    public constructor(
        fields?: {
          id?: string;
          location?: string;
          displayName?: string;
          otherAttribute?: string;
        }) {
        if (fields) Object.assign(this, fields);
    }
}

const optionalCLassInstnace: Optional<User, "location" | "otherAttribute"> = new User({
  "id": "1", 
  "displayName": "Optional"
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it with Pick (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) but it creates a new type instead of retaining the original User type. When I constructed the object like you suggested in the answer, cherryPickedInstance is just a object literal, not a User object.

Comment: @Bryan Please refer my edit. I hope that is what you wanted.