# What is a placeholder for primitive types other than string in React useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

so lets say I have a `Person` in my app. The `type` looks like this:

```
type Person = {
  name: string,
  email: string,
  height: number,
  accountBalance: number,
  isParent: boolean
}
```

When I want to want to use this person in my state in a form for example:

```
const [person, setPerson] = useState<Person>(...) // What to put here
```

As default values for the name and email I would just empty strings:

```
useState({name: "", email: "", ...}
```

However, what are my options for placeholders for height, accountBalance and isParent? If I set `isParent` to `false` for example or `accountBalance` to 0 they would portray a meaningful value that could be false.

Comment: If the fields are not required you should make them [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optional property class in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942141/optional-property-class-in-typescript)

Comment: They are required :D

Comment: Then your question as posed doesn't seem to make sense. If there's a valid state where the fields have no value they should either be optional, nullable or accept undefined.

Comment: Like I said it is a form, these things are required to be filled out by a user. For example, before a Person can be created there must a be a name and email filled in, yet an empty string when initialising the component is not much of a value either.

Comment: `0` and `false`?

Comment: Well, this is opinion, but we make them optional (initially set to undefined) and let form validation handle them having to have a value when the form is actually submitted.